# Cache not getting cleared on re-opening the same url in another tab in the same browser window

Tags: java, html, xhtml, browser-cache

After accessing a particular url I need to clear the cache on closing the tab or reloading the url.
I am using the following META tags to clear the cache(in HEAD)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="**; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

For a particular scenario I am opening the url `http://***/1` in a browser tab.
When I open the same url `http://***/1` in another new tab in the same browser window(without closing the previously opened tab), the cache is not getting cleared.
Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

EDIT: I donot want the user to clear the cache manually.

Comment: ctrl+f5 clears the cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set response headers for `HttpServletResponse` in servlet class or directly on jsp page:

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```